# How do you defeat royal ripeness in Final Fantasy XIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

He's so hard! He's invincible! I just need advice on how to beat the hell outta him! Please I've literally tried for months and he won't die! Advice needed make it a simple answer! *sigh*

Comment: Have you finished the game?  He's awfully hard to beat before that.

Comment: Short answer. face him later, you can go back in time to kick his butt at a much later stage

Focus on getting serah and noel stronger

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways

the first way is the way you have to beat him and that's to weaken him by solving the paradoxs in the area by finding Fragments and opening up other gates, i think there's 2 gates which you have to go though, after you solve them he becomes the smaller and weaker Mutantomato, if you can't beat him at this point i would suggest grinding to build up CP for Serah and Noel while getting items for your monsters, best method is COM > RAV > RAV (for Staggering), COM > RAV > MED (for healing while trying to stagger), RAV > RAV > RAV (for trying to get the chain gauge to 999%) and COM > COM > COM (for dealing huge damage combined with a high Chain Gauge)

the other way leads to a Paradox Ending and it involves killing him without weakening him, i would not suggests doing this until you've beaten the game and it also helps if you were strong enough to S Rank the final boss (though i did it first time around but if you can't S Rank the final boss then you best do that first so you know your strong enough). In this battle you'll need a SEN to buff your party, you'll want Noel for this so he can get Protectga and Shellga and make him leader so you can pull them off, after that do Veilga just to help avoid status affects, now you need to to switch between COM > RAV > RAV and RAV > RAV > RAV cause you need to build up that chain gauge to deal him the damage needed to negate the amount he's recovering by, stock up on healing items so you can avoid having to use a MED but if you need one then use a COM > MED > SEN formation so you can reduce the damage taken with the SEN's abilities, the MED can heal and the COM can augment the chain gauge and prevent a loss of all your heard work, you can go RAV > RAV > RAV to build it up quickly since you can't stagger him but keep in mind that the chain gauge will drop quicker the more RAV attacks you chain up so make sure you use a COM to stabilize it, when it's max go for the COM > COM > COM to do some beating

you can increase the damage you do to both Royal Ripeness and Mutantomato by having a SAB in your party aswell and casting DeProtect and DeShell, it doesn't matter who you choose since both Serah and Noel have got both or you can even use a monster however i normally put SEN and SAB in separate Paradigms with a COM and SEN so that while buffing/debuffing i still have a strong line of defense